# index.php not found in url of cloned Magento Site on Development server?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have cloned a live Magento 1.5.0.0 site to my development server (windows wamp)

the development server does not have an .htaccess file in the roor directory but i have copied one into my root directory from another magento install?

Every thing seems to be configure ok the database is connected ok, I have set up alias which loads the index.php page ok but the url's do not work , so if i click on the contact us page the server error is:

> The requested URL /vhosts/petextra/magento/index.php was not found on this server.

The adress bar url for the same is: `http://127.0.0.1/petextra/contact-us/`.

If I manualy type in the index.php in the address bar

```
http://127.0.0.1/petextra/index.php/contact-us/`
```

then the page loads ok.

Some how the url is not including the `index.php`?

Has anybody got any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: you forgot to copy .htaccess ?

Comment: the development server does not have an .htaccess file in the roor directory but i have copied one into my root directory from another magento install ? thanks

Comment: @Anton S still have the same problem with the .htaccess copied over, do i have to configure it ?

Comment: ensure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your dev site and .htaccess is in place or turn off url rewriting from magento admin

Comment: @Anton S working ! turned off - RewriteEngine off in .htaccess file and set configuration>web> Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > No thanks for your help, shall i post this as an answers or do you want to do it ? many thanks for your help...

Comment: added this as answer you can accept it for others to know if you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ensure that:

- mod_rewrite is enabled on your dev site
- .htaccess is in place
- .htaccess file >  RewriteEngine off
- or turn off url rewriting from magento admin  `configuration>web> Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites > No`

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, The  problem was that i enabled the search engines Optimization but later switched to NO. is working fine after that